# Memberships in multiple currencies?

Tags: civimember, currency

I am working for an international NGO with memberships. They want to be able to sell memberships in USD, EUR and GBP. The contribution forms will deal with this for donations, etc. The contributions form will also switch the membership currency to the one give in the Amounts page, but the value is the value given in the Membership type. Logical enough, but the membership type seems to be tied only to the default currency. Is there a way to define a membership prices set or even a separate membership in another currency?

Keith

Comment: I should add that our default currency is presently USD, so membership types seem currently locked to that currency.

Comment: are you using Price Sets?

Comment: I have the exact same question.
Frederik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this

1. Create contribution page and price set for each currency. Provide a list of contribution page to user and based on currency they can use the contribution page
2. Create contribution page and price set for each currency. Add currency field on each contribution page using [buildform](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) hook and on selection of currency load the respective contribution page.
3. Create a price set with radio field and have all the currency as options with same membership type. Using [buildform](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) or [buildAmount](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildAmount/) hook change the amount or field label to include currency(not necessary if can add it price field option label). On submit of 1st page set currency in [postProcess](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_postProcess/) hook in $form so that right currency is set to send it to payment processor.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Turning that third option into an extension would be a useful project!

Comment: Agreed! This is been an requirement for so many people in the community.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I haven't quite reached the end of my odyssey, but I feel like I'm on the right track now.

Comment: In the third option, It is definitely simpler for the user. But I was thinking from the Contribution Page Form Creator, will that person have to set amounts for all different currencies separately or probably translate amount given in one currency to different currency. Which is better? I am talking in case of price sets.